# Discriminant of a polynomial and power sums polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, discriminant

Let $f(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_n$ be a monic polynomial with coefficients in a field $K$. Its discriminant is defined like this:
$$\Delta(f)=\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2$$
Now we define the Newton's power sums polynomials: $p_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1^k+\dots+x_n^k$.

It is claimed the following equality:
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2=
\begin{vmatrix}
p_0 & p_1 & \dots & p_{n-1} \\
p_1 & p_2 & \dots & p_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{n-1} & p_n & \dots & p_{2n-2}
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I tried to show that by induction and writing the determinant using minor formula but I still have terms I don't know. Either way, it seems quite cumbersome to work with and I'm sure there is a better way to do this. Any advice?

Comment: The $x_i$ are evidently roots to $f$ so it is cleanest to assume $\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed.  See the 'addendum' here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460264/if-a-has-distinct-eigenvalues-then-all-matrices-close-enough-to-a-also-have/ [this assumes you know the determinant for a Vandermonde matrix]

Comment: The square root of the discriminant is the determinant of the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), and the product of the Vandermonde matrix with its transpose is the matrix of power sums